# USB soundcard with MPD - only outputs static

Tags: usb, alsa, soundcard, mpd

I used to have a Muse Mini DAC USB soundcard on my Media Player Daemon machine, but now need to switch to using a Native Instruments Audio2DJ USB soundcard instead. `aplay some_wav_file.wav` works fine and sounds great with the Audio2DJ card, but when playing MP3s with MPD all I get is a loud static noise. I have previously used this card successfully with Mixxx on another machine, and it is compatible with Linux's `snd_usb_caiaq` driver, but it seems some configuration is needed. Any ideas?

My /etc/mpd.conf has the following audio output settings:

```
audio_output {
        type            "alsa"
        name            "Audio2DJ"
        device          "hw:0,0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure why this works, but after seeing several other people with USB sound cards mentioning a need to address the card with `plughw:0,0` instead of `hw:0,0` I changed my `/etc/mpd.conf` to:

```
audio_output {
        type            "alsa"
        name            "Audio2DJ"
        device          "plughw:0,0"
}
```

Apparently this adds an extra resampling layer between the card hardware and ALSA which allows MPD to feed it formats that are not natively supported by the hardware. I haven't tested very thoroughly but sound quality *seems* to be ok with this setting - certainly a lot better than the white noise I had previously at least.